# How to Put Emoticons into Chat Text Area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emoticons

I am working on an instant messenger and want to enable "chatters" to add emojis to their chats. This is what I have so far.

```
<template name="chat_page">
    <h2>Type in the box below to send a message!</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well well-lg">
        {{#each messages}}
          {{> chat_message}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <form class="js-send-chat">  
        <div class="form-group">  
          <input class="form-control" id="input-emoticon" type="text" name="chat" placeholder="type a message here..." />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: you can use unicode emojis like any "special char"

Comment: Thanks for replying Dan. Trying to implement EmojiOne. Still struggling. Any links to help in this endeavor would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template name="emotis">
  {{{ parseEmoticons }}}
</template>

<template name="chat_page">
    <h2>Type in the box below to send a message!</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well well-lg">
        {{#each messages}}
          {{> chat_message}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <form class="js-send-chat">  
        <div class="form-group">  
          <input class="form-control" id="input-emoticon" type="text" name="chat" placeholder="type a message here..." />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="chat_message">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span class=avatar> <img src="/{{creatorAvatar sentBy}}" class="creatorImg"> </span>
      <span class="text">On {{timeStamp}} </span>
      <span class="bold">{{getUserById sentBy}} said: {{{parseEmoticons text}}} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
<br>
<br>
</template>
```

Comment: Here is one possible way of going about it using mattimo:emoticons and https://github.com/dubvfan87/meteor-emoticons.